# Error al subir datos a MySQL mediante PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

hoy estoy probando subir datos de un formulario de registro a mi db mediante PDO, me arroja "Error" que es el return que tengo establecido al enviar los datos.

```
    <?php 

require_once('models/connection.php');

class Data extends Connection {
    public function RegisterUserModel($dataModel, $table) {

        #Preparando conexion a la base de datos.
        $stmt = Connection::connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO $table(user, pass, email) VALUES (:user,:password,:email)");


        #Vinculando parametros a los valores que se almacenarán en la base de datos.
        $stmt->bindParam(":user", $dataModel["user"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":password", $dataModel["pass"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":email", $dataModel["email"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        #Ejecutando el registro del usuario en la base de datos.
        if($stmt->execute()){
            return "Succes";
        } else {
            return "Error";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

este es el archivo connection.php:

```
    <?php

class Connection {

    public function connect() {

        $link = new PDO("mysql:localhost;dbname=encomienda;","root","");
        return $link;

    }
}

?>
```

y este es el archivo controller.php donde se envian los datos del formulario:

```
<?php 

class MvcController {

    public function view(){
        include('view/login.view.php');
    }

    public function LinkPagesController() {
        if(isset($_GET['action'])){
            $linkcontroller = $_GET['action'];    
        } else {
            $linkcontroller = "index";
        }

        $request = LinkPageClass::LinkPagesModel($linkcontroller);

        include $request;
    }

    public function RegisterUserController() {

       if(isset($_POST["user"])) {

           $dataController = array("user"=>$_POST["user"], 
                          "pass"=>$_POST["password"], 
                          "email"=>$_POST["email"]);

           $request = Data::RegisterUserModel($dataController, "user");

           echo $request;
       }

    }


}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te falta colocar el host, en connection.php tienes

```
$link = new PDO("mysql:localhost;dbname=encomienda;","root","");
```

y es

```
$link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=encomienda;","root","");
```

además es muy recomendable que guardes los datos de la conexión en variables, así que te quedaría:

```
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$host = 'localhost';
$db = 'encomienda';
$link = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;", $user, $pass);
```

Comment: oh man! gracias! he estado ya 2 días buscando el bendito error y era algo tan simple como eso :/ gracias!! y lo de guardar en variable no lo había pensado, gracias!